# How to Subtract Pageviews in Google Data Studio using a CASE statement?

Tags: google-analytics, case, looker-studio

I want to subtract `Pageviews` of a particular page from `Pageviews` of a different page, but when I try using `COUNT` with `CASE`, I get `1`:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN page = "www.link1.com" THEN 1 END)
```

This gives me a wrong `COUNT`:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN page = "www.link1.com" THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

What I ultimately want to do is:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN page="www.link1.com" OR page = "www.link2.com" THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) - COUNT(CASE
    WHEN page="www.link3.com" THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

I want the `COUNT` of `Users` who have visited `link3` but **NOT** from `link1` and `link2`. These links are steps in a funnel. `link1` is the first step in the funnel but `link2` and `link3` have more `Pageviews`. I want to show how many users have come from sources other than the previous funnel step (i.e, `link1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

One way it can be achieved is by using either the RegEx Formula (#2) or the [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) Statement (#3), however, as `Pageviews` is an aggregated Metric, the [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) will produce the below message when created at the Data Source:

> Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7569962#troubleshoot-calculated-fields).

For future reference, added an Image:
[image]

The solution is to first use Data Blending to disaggregate the `Pageviews` field (#1) and then apply the Calculated Field (#2 or #3):

### 1) [Data Blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420)

**Data Source 1**

- ***Join Key 1***: `Date`
- ***Join Key 2***: `Page`
- ***Metric***: `Pageviews`

**Data Source 2**

- ***Join Key 1***: `Date`
- ***Join Key 2***: `Page`

An image to elaborate:
[image]

### 2) RegEx Formula

```sql
SUM(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(Page, ";", Pageviews), "(www\\.link1\\.com|www\\.link2\\.com);(.*)", "\\2") AS NUMBER ), 0 ) ) - SUM(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(Page, ";", Pageviews), "(www\\.link3\\.com);(.*)", "\\2") AS NUMBER ), 0 ) )
```

### 3) (Alternative Calculated Field) CASE Statement

```sql
SUM(CASE
    WHEN Page IN ("www.link1.com", "www.link2.com") THEN Pageviews
    ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE
    WHEN Page IN ("www.link3.com") THEN Pageviews
    ELSE 0 END)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3e72d2c6-a470-49e6-b457-05d50f118bfd) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]